# Is This Wood Still Good? (Water Stained or Rotten)

Tags: wood, tile, floor, replacement

I have an attachment on the side of my house, basically an enclosed porch but could also be a mudroom. One of the doors leads to a deck where the prior owners let the gutter downspout fall out of place, which let water collect on the deck and get into this small room. I'm wondering if the floor is still good (just stained) or rotting. I was planning on finishing the room which includes tiling the floor. Do I need to replace the wood prior to doing this?

Comment: It looks like water stains. Take a screwdriver and press it into the surface especially in the groves. If the wood is rotten the screwdriver will dig in. If the wood is sound it will just leave a mark. This is how home inspectors test around suspected areas for rot.

Comment: @EdBeal Please post that as an answer so that the OP can accept it if it helps them.

Comment: If you're tiling, unless using something flexible (like vinyl), you will want to lay down a plywood subfloor instead of these deck boards. The deck boards, even if not rotten, are probably not a suitable subfloor for tile & grout.

Comment: @ShimonRura thank you for the advice. It's a small room (6x6) so I'd be okay with going in either direction. Probably vinyl if it's one less step but this extra information is much appreciated.

Comment: You might consider sanding, staining, and sealing the existing wood floor. Could save you time and money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like water stains. Take a screwdriver and press it into the surface especially in the groves. If the wood is rotten the screwdriver will dig in. If the wood is sound it will just leave a mark. This is how home inspectors test around suspected areas for rot.